# Adaptive sample size for determining the significance of difference between two non-parametric distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two non-parametric distributions, A and B, and I would like to determine if they are significantly different (say, by the p-value of a U-test). Normally, I would sample $n=1000$ from distribution A to form a dataset A, and similarly sample $n=1000$ from distribution B to form a dataset B. Then, I apply the U-test to the two sample groups A and B to get the result.

I wonder if there is an adaptive way to perform the U-test. For example, I gradually increase the sample size for A and B, and at some point, say $n=600$ for both groups, I am already very confident that A and B are significantly different. So I stop there and save time for the remaining 400*2 samples.

I am unsure whether it is scientifically correct to simply perform a U-test every time when I increase $n$. Are there any papers or materials on this topic? Thank you.

Comment: You should search for "Sequential Probability Ratio Test" or SPRT.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question a bit. I think your answer only apply to parameteric distribtuions in my case.

Comment: The same theory applies to non-parametric distributions.  See this [link](https://journals.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/7650/76502O/A-novel-non-parametric-sequential-probability-ratio-test-method-for/10.1117/12.848753.short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this chapter in Daniel Lakens online book [Improving your statistical inferences](https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/10-sequential.html).

The problem you need to be aware of when looking at data multiple times is inflated type-1 error rates. Or in other words, simply doing a statistical test every time you increase n would indeed be scientifically incorrect.

For example, here's code that simulates two normal distributions with no difference between them. The code then does a non-parametric test of difference  every time we add a pair of participants, starting at 5 per cell. (whether the test is non-parametric or parametric is not relevant here)

```
set.seed(25)
A <- rnorm(1000)
B <- rnorm(1000)
p.values <- c()
for(i in 5:1000){
  p.values[i] <- wilcox.test(A[1:i],B[1:i])$p.value
}
plot(p.values, type = "l")
abline(h = 0.05, col = "red")
```

[image: plot of p-values when testing after every added n-pair]

Since p-values are uniform when the null-hypothesis is true, they turn into sort of a random walk that's likely to cross the 0.05 limit eventually. In the example above we would have wrongly stopped early.

To not run into this problem you need to do define some things before-hand like what effect you are looking for an how many times you aim to look at the data, then do a type of correction for multiple testing made for sequential analysis (Pockock correction). I recommend the book chapter I linked.